# GIT web deployment: post-receive hook runs, but files not changing in web-root

Tags: git, githooks, web-development-server

I am using [this gist's](https://gist.github.com/noelboss/3fe13927025b89757f8fb12e9066f2fa) guidelines for setting up automated deployment for my organization's website. The post-receive hook seems to be running, but the actual files in my site's web root are not being updated to reflect the changes that I push to the server. My post-receive hook is:

```html
#!/bin/bash
while read oldrev newrev ref
do
    # only checking out the master (or whatever branch you would like to deploy)
    if [[ $ref =~ .*/master$ ]];
    then
        echo "Master ref received.  Deploying master branch to production..."
        git --work-tree=/home/sites/3a/5/5b0bf591fd/public_html/ --git-dir=/home/sites/3a/5/5b0bf591fd/annapoliscodeandcoffee.git/ checkout -f
    else
        echo "Ref $ref successfully received.  Doing nothing: only the master branch may be deployed on this server."
    fi
done
```

I am not sure what is going wrong.  Is it possible that this has to do with my public_html folder's chmod permissions? They are currently set as -rw-r--r-- for all files located there.

Also, in case it is relevant, the hosting service I am using is Ecowebhosting.co.uk.

Comment: Have you verified that the script is running?

Comment: Yes, because "Master ref received.  Deploying master branch to production..." is being printed to the console.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you don't see anything when doing a git push, that means the script itself is not running.
Make sure the script is named `post-receive` (no extension) in `project.git/hooks/` on the server side, and is executable (`chmod 755`).

Second, [eco web hosting](https://www.ecowebhosting.co.uk/) is a cloud hosting service: check with the what kind of program they allow to run.
If you are using an https url, try switching to an ssh one (if you deploy a public key to your eco web hosting `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` account file
)

Comment: Hi VonC, and thanks for the quick response.

I can verify that the script is actually running, because the console is outputting "Master ref received.  Deploying master branch to production..."

I spent my afternoon setting up an SSH connection to my ecowebhosting server and making sure it works, so I know that's taken care of.

So I'm wondering if perhaps there is something wrong with my work-tree path (which I got from going into my public_html directory using bash and using the 'pwd' command), or if something with ecowebhosting is preventing the files from being changed.

Comment: Do you think that adding group write permissions to the files in public_html might help?

Comment: @JamesS you can test addingthe permission. Try also `checkout -f master` instead of `checkout -f`. Or `checkout -f -- .`